# Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, persistência

O erro `Cannot read property 'query' of undefined` é reportado ao tentar salvar dados na base. No entanto, a property query funciona para o getNews. Ex:

```
function NewsDAO(database){
    this._database = database;
}

NewsDAO.prototype.getNews = function(callback){
    this._database.query('SELECT * FROM news', callback);
}
NewsDAO.prototype.saveNotice = (notice, callback) =>{
    this._database.query('INSERT INTO noticias SET ?', notice, callback);
    console.log(this._database);
}

module.exports = () => {
    return NewsDAO;
}
```

Quando dou um `console.log` no `_database` no método `getNews()`, consigo ver todas as propriedades. Quando faço o mesmo no `saveNotice()`, retorna um `undefined`.
O que poderia ser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A expressão lambda, chamada `arrow function` em JavaScript, não é apenas uma forma reduzida de escrever uma função, outra característica dela é não fazer o `bind` na instancia na qual ela está sendo invocada, ou seja, numa expressão lambda, o `this` não se refere ao objeto em que ela foi declarada.

Declarando dessa forma, `this` irá se referir ao escopo superior ao objeto, ou seja `this` será o `window` (ou o próprio módulo no caso do NodeJS):

```
NewsDAO.prototype.saveNotice = (notice, callback) => {
    console.log(this);
}
```

Agora se você declarar a função como a expressão `function`, `this` irá se referir ao objeto e a função irá funcionar da forma que você deseja:

```
NewsDAO.prototype.saveNotice = function(notice, callback) {
    console.log(this);
}
```

Comment: Deu super certo! Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.